# Unlocking a "locked by another user" file from a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-server

I opened a word doc file in a SharePoint library via a channel tab in MS Teams app. I closed the app without making changes. Now when I try to delete the file from the library I get file locked by another user. When I try to delete the same file form SharePoint in my Edge browser, it says it is locked by me.

I have tried to "take ownership of the file" via the library settings but it does not show up in the list of "files which have no checked in version" 
I cleared my browser cache and rebooted but it didn't help.

Please do not offer solutions that involve PowerShell or designer or code... I shouldn't have to write code to use SharePoint.

Comment: Here's a couple links that may help you out regarding file locks in SharePoint. It's pretty detailed on how and why these files tend to get locked. http://www.paulliebrand.com/2008/01/04/document-is-locked-for-editing/
http://www.paulliebrand.com/2010/04/12/document-is-locked-for-editing-part-2/

Answer (score 4):

I had something similar happen a few weeks ago. SharePoint eventually unlocked the file.  It took over 30 minutes for the unlock to occur. It seems to be something MS is aware of.  If you can't wait you can try opening the file in the Office Word client then File > Info > Manage Document > Check Out then Check In > Save.  That seemed to work for some.  Here's a reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Cannot-Release-Lock-on-SharePoint-Online-File/td-p/59694

Answer (score 3):

1. You can wait 10 minutes before opening/deleting the document . http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899709
2. Close all office client application , and repair office . control panel – program – choose office and right-click – repair .
3. Clear officefilecache : C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0
4. Reset "WebClient" service in "Services.msc"
5. Using PowerShell to unlock file : http://www.geekmungus.co.uk/microsoft-windows/microsoftsharepoint2013-lockedfileerrorfileislockedbyanotheruser

Comment: link to kb899709 broken. unsure if it's this text: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/upload-failed-this-file-is-locked-for-editing-by/411c5eb7-11dd-4ee6-beba-2a328ce923b4